# Make my website button do the same as submit

Tags: button, popup

so i have this code and it works for my form submit button but i want it to work on my link button

JavaScript:

```
function showLoading() {
document.getElementById('loadingmsg').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('loadingover').style.display = 'block'; }
```

HTML/CSS:

```
 <style type="text/css">
      #loadingmsg {
      color: black;
      background: #fff; 
      padding: 10px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 100;
      margin-right: -25%;
      margin-bottom: -25%;
      }
      #loadingover {
      background: black;
      z-index: 99;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
      filter: alpha(opacity=80);
      -moz-opacity: 0.8;
      -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
</style>

<div id='loadingmsg' style='display: none;'>Redirecting, please wait...</div>
<div id='loadingover' style='display: none;'></div>
<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='refreshpage();showLoading();'> 
<input name='refresh' type="image" src="images/Next-Page-Button.gif" height="60" width="173" border="0" value='Refresh'> 
</form>
```

And i want it to work on this button

```
<li><a href="facebook.php"><img src="images/logos/facebooklikeicon.png" height="25" border="0" /> Earn Coins Facebook</a></li>
```

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<a href="facebook.php" onclick="return showLoading();"><img src="images/logos/facebooklikeicon.png" height="25" border="0" /> Earn Coins Facebook</a>
```